# Why is the var statement omitted when extending Ember.Object?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

From the [Ember.js documentation](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_the-ember-object-model):

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
   // [..]
});
```

It's the first definition of `Person`, so why is the `var` statement omitted?

---

`var` is also missing in some other places, e.g. [Ember.Application.Create](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Application.html) or [Ember.StateManager.Create](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Application.html#doc=Ember.StateManager&src=false).

---

Guys, I know what happens when `var` is omitted. But there doesn't seem to be a good reason to do it, like this it's just confusing people.

Comment: In the documentation it's there to not confuse the reader at the very beginning with the - documented farther below - concept of an `Ember.Namespace` respectively `Ember.Application`. So this is maybe a bad example. In general you want to declare your classes and instances inside a global available namespace, see my answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's declared globally so Ember and Handlebars can resolve bindings.

In case of a view for example it's necessary so it can be instantiated in a Handlebars template via the `view` helper:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view MyView}}
         my view's template
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:​

```js
MyView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

---

The following example doesn't work when the controller is declared with a `var` statement, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/uzsd6/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{controller.name}} - {{secondController.name}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
var controller = Ember.Object.create({
    name: 'my name'
});

var secondController = Ember.Object.create({
    nameBinding: 'controller.name'
});​
```

---

If the controllers are declared on a global available object, the `App` namespace in this case, the the bindings can be resolved, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/kUmje/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{App.controller.name}} - {{App.secondController.name}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.controller = Ember.Object.create({
    name: 'my name'
});

App.secondController = Ember.Object.create({
    nameBinding: 'App.controller.name'
});​
```

---

You should take a look at *the Emberist* 's blog about [Naming Conventions](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html) in `Ember.js`.

Comment: Sorry for the late accepting, but I stopped learning about Ember until recently, so I waited until I actually understood it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You only use the `var` keyword if you want to declare the variable in the local scope. Declaring a variable without `var` will result in the variable being available in the global scope. This is usually done with classes as you want to access them from anywhere in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This statement, if not preceded by `var Person` always creates variable in global scope (window in browser's case), so I guess it's just sloppiness or there may be some reason Person should be global and accessible from anywhere. I agree with @Femaref, this is a pseudo "Class" so it is meant to construct instances like `var person = new Person()` therefore it should be accesible from other places.

Anyway, it's always a bad habit to pollute the global namespace. The person class should reside in some "namespace hash".